# What is causing my tap (faucet) to not work properly?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, hot-water

**Background**

My flat is on the 3rd floor of a converted Victorian building and the mains water pipe to my flat has a [booster pump](https://www.plumbworld.co.uk/salamander-homeboost-16-bar-19703-32082) installed on the ground floor to improve water pressure. Whenever any taps are turned on, there is a noticeable increase in pressure after ~20 seconds after the effect of the pump kicks in. Hot water is heated on demand by a modern boiler.

**The problem**

The bathroom sink has separate taps for hot and cold water. This is the only standalone hot tap in the flat (the rest are mixer taps). When the hot tap is opened, it can only be turned a ~full turn before it can't be turned further, and no water comes out, no matter how long it is left in that position. I must close the tap a ~quarter turn, then can open the tap another ~half turn, and repeat this to slowly edge it open until water begins to flow. Once open, it can be closed to the original position where it stuck, and water will continue coming out - indeed water continues to flow happily until completely closed. The standalone water tap on the same basin has no such problem, nor do any other water outlets.

**What is causing this and what can I do about it?**

I thought it might be something to do with the combination of pressure lags due to the pump and being directly connected to the boiler causing some sort of vacuum lock or something, but the issue is unaffected if other hot taps are running (i.e. ensuring the pump and boiler are already engaged and running). I can't find any similar problems by googling but I might not have the right terminology.

Comment: Perhaps the cartridge/washer has become separated from the handle, and you need water pressure to help create enough friction so the cartridge or washer can move. Have you opened the tap itself to investigate?